# How to filter by multiple words C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i hope someone can helpme
im working in c# with entity framework 6

i need to search in a "DESCRIPTION" field of my table "PRODUCTS" the value of textbox, but the text by separate in any order, i can explain better with my code:

```
string[] palabras = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
string palabraABuscar = "";                    
for (int i = 0; i <= palabras.Length - 1; i++)
{
 palabraABuscar = palabras[i];
 query = query.Where(a => a.DESCRIPCION.Contains(palabraABuscar));
}
```

the idea is if the user enter "lala1 lala2" the program filter all the products that contains that two words, example:

the program must show the products "CAMERA lala2 with lala1" and "lala1 BOX lala2"
the program must not show "Computer lala1" either "shower lala2"

With my code the program only filter the products by the last word ("lala"), maybe replace the first where, i use a for cicle because i dont know how many

Comment: What you might need full-text search, which is not supported directly by EF. You will have to resort to a workaround to make it work.

Comment: IMO, your current code should work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your currenct code should work as expected, beacuse `Where` method adds each query with `and`. Or you can try another option (@Ghasan also stated in comments):

```
string[] palabras = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
query = query.Where(a => palabras.All(p => a.DESCRIPCION.Contains(p)));
```

If nor your current code, nor this works for you, then check if you correctly split data and be sure that `query` is correct until you reach above code. Additionally you can check generated SQL query like:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine; // Or something similar.
```

Comment: your answer rememberme i can check the generated SQL and confirmed me that my code should work.
but i still cant solve my problem, i try with my code and get this sql code:
{SELECT`Project1`.`IDPRODUCTO`, `Project1`.`DESCRIPCION`FROM `producto` AS `Project1` WHERE ((1 = `Project1`.`ESTADO`) AND (`Project1`.`DESCRIPCION` LIKE @p__linq__0)) AND (`Project1`.`DESCRIPCION` LIKE @p__linq__1) ORDER BY `Project1`.`IDPRODUCTO` ASC}

i dont see the error :/

my program still show the products like was filtering with only the last word entered by the user

Comment: Then the problem is not in your code, check parameters `p__linq__0` and `p__linq__1` and try executing that query in databas @Alexisenp

Comment: do you know why the generated sql code show me that parameters instead the values ?
and how to see the values of that parameters ?? :S

Comment: @Alexisenp, Generally their values are shown below the query. 
`-- p__linq__0: 'lala1' (Type = Object)
-- Executing at 18.08.2016 11:27:55 +04:00
-- Completed in 43 ms with result: OracleDataReader`

Comment: finally i fixit thanks to your help, the two variables generated p__linq__0 and p__linq__0 has the same value i dont know why, i print the variable palabraABuscar and the values was rigth, finally i modified the code like this:
`
    string[] palabras = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');                    
    for (int i = 0; i <= palabras.Length - 1; i++)
    {
      string palabraABuscar = palabras[i];
      query = query.Where(a => a.DESCRIPCION.Contains(palabraABuscar));
    }
`
i declare the variable inside the for cicle and it works as i expected.
Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
query = query.Where(a => a.DESCRIPCION.Contains(palabraABuscar));
```

with

```
query = query.Where(a => palabraABuscar.All(x => a.DESCRIPCION.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Sorry guys when i use that code i get the error (i think should be palabras as @AdilMammadov):
InnerException {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s%) OR (CASE WHEN (`Extent1`.`DESCRIPCION` LIKE %s%) THEN (1)  WHEN (`Extent1`.' at line 16"} System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}
i dont know why :/, im still triying to figure out why

Comment: looks like a MariaDB bug to me. Can you try to run `query.ToList().Where(` ? If this works, the error should be in the framework that translates linq to sql